# java/ant jar file SecurityException

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am trying to build a *.jar file using apache ant. I start with a compile target:

```
<target name="pdfcompile">
    <property name="pdfclasses.dir" value="pdfclasses" />
    <property name="pdfsrc.dir" value="src/com/mespas/client/pdfviewer" />
    <mkdir dir="${pdfclasses.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${pdfsrc.dir}" destdir="${pdfclasses.dir}" classpathref="path.pdf" />
</target>
```

with path.pdf is defined as followed:

```
<path id="path.pdf">
    <pathelement path="${project.client.lib.dir}/rhino.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${project.client.lib.dir}/jPDFViewer.jar" />
</path>
```

After the compile target I want to build the jar:

```
<target name="pdfjar" depends="pdfcompile" >
    <property name="jar.file" value="mespasPdfViewer.jar" />
    <property name="jar.file" value="mespasPdfViewer.jar" />
    <property name="main-class" value="com.mespas.client.pdfviewer.MespasPDFViewer" />
    <property name="pdfclasses.dir" value="pdfclasses" />

    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}/lib"/>
    <copy file="${project.client.lib.dir}/rhino.jar" tofile="${jar.dir}/lib/rhino.jar"/>
    <copy file="${project.client.lib.dir}/jPDFViewer.jar" tofile="${jar.dir}/lib/jPDFViewer.jar"/>

    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar.file}" basedir="${pdfclasses.dir}" >
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${jar.dir}/lib" includes="rhino.jar jPDFViewer.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.mespas.client.pdfviewer.MespasPDFViewer"/>
        </manifest>         
        <fileset dir="${project.classes.dir}">
            <include name="com/mespas/client/pdfviewer/*.class" />
        </fileset>
    </jar>  

    <copy file="${jar.dir}/${jar.file}" tofile="${project.client.lib.dir}/${jar.file}" overwrite="true" />
    <delete file="${jar.file}"/>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${pdfclasses.dir}" />
    </delete>

</target>
```

The build is working fine but when I try to launch the jar I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

What am I doing wrong? I exclude the META-INF folder from the external jars (rhino.pdf and jPDFViewer.pdf) but still get this exception when launching the jar. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that works just fine. I adjusted the build target as followed:

```
<target name="pdfjar" depends="pdfcompile" >
    <property name="jar.file" value="mespasPdfViewer.jar" />
    <property name="jar.dir" value="pdfViewer" />
    <property name="main-class" value="com.mespas.client.pdfviewer.MespasPDFViewer" />
    <property name="pdfclasses.dir" value="pdfclasses" />

    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}/lib"/>
    <copy file="${project.client.lib.dir}/rhino.jar" tofile="${jar.dir}/lib/rhino.jar"/>
    <copy file="${project.client.lib.dir}/jPDFViewer.jar" tofile="${jar.dir}/lib/jPDFViewer.jar"/>


    <jar jarfile="${jar.dir}/deps.jar">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${jar.dir}/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </zipgroupfileset>
    </jar>
    <sleep seconds="1" />
    <jar jarfile="${jar.dir}/mespasPdfViewer.jar" basedir="${pdfclasses.dir}">
        <zipfileset src="${jar.dir}/deps.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.mespas.client.pdfviewer.MespasPDFViewer" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <copy file="${jar.dir}/${jar.file}" tofile="${project.client.lib.dir}/${jar.file}" overwrite="true" />
    <delete file="${jar.file}"/>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${pdfclasses.dir}" />
    </delete>

</target>
```

This allowed the script to remove the signature before repacking the jar.